# File says permission denied, despite the fact that I have run 'chmod 777' on the file

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod, jgrasp, crostini

I recently installed jGRASP on ChromeOS Crostini (like debian linux). Whenever I try to run any .java file in the IDE, this is the output:

```
(Cannot run program "/home/aarnap/jgrasp_bdl206_16/jgrasp/internal_bin/sys_run": error=13, Permission denied)
Check permissions on the file.
```

This is despite the fact that I have modified the permissions of the file 'sys_run' multiple times

Steps I took to try and solve this problem:

1. Run chmod +x on the file
2. Run chmod 777 on the file

Running the file myself via terminal works fine

Here is the output of `ls -l` after `chmod +x sys_run`:

```
rwxr-xr-x 1 aarnap aarnap   23104 Mar 28 16:38 sys_run
```

And the output after `chmod 777 sys_run`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 aarnap aarnap   23104 Mar 28 16:38 sys_run
```

Expected output: jGRASP does not give me a permission error and the .java file successfully launches
Actual output: jGRASP gives me a permission error

Comment: You need to have +x on every directory leading up to the file

Comment: Just tried it but unfortunately it did not work. I did chmod +x on home, then aarnap, then jgrasp_bdl206_16, then jgrasp and finally internal_bin.

Comment: Look at the output of `mount` and check if the underlying filesystem for the home directory is mounted with the `noexec` flag. `

Comment: YOU need to have `+x`. `chmod +x` gives SOMEONE +x, but not necessarily you. If you don't know who you are in relation to the owner and group of the directory, you can use `chmod a+x` to give +x to All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed; 'that other guy' comment was technically correct. I was using chmod by itself on each folder and its children instead of using **chmod -R**. The -R stands for recursive and greatly simplifies the process as you only need to do it on the parent folder.

So I ran: `chmod -R jgrasp_bdl206_16`